# Joomla one time self registration with unique code

Tags: joomla, registration

I am trying to find out if there is an extension for Joomla where you can use a unique coupon code to access the self registration form. After the code has been used it should get invalid so that a user can't hand down the coupon code to other users.

Does anybody know an extension which has such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

you can try one of these extensions:

[JRPassphrase (Free)](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/6660)

> Now you can control who registers on your site. This plugin and module
>   allows you to control or restrict user registration to only those
>   people who have received a "passphrase". This is useful for clubs,
>   organizations, churches, schools, etc that want to limit registration
>   to current and new members who have received the passphrase via email,
>   newsletter, etc. The correct passphrase must be entered before a user
>   can submit their registration.

[InviteX (Commercial)](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/bookmark-a-recommend/12178)

> InviteX- The most comprehensive Invitations system with native api contacts import, automated invitations, intelligent invites, rich
>   invites content, tracking, points integration & much much more.